# Animated status bar style transition, a la iPod app

Tags: iphone

In the iPod app, the navigation views have the default status bar style, and the Now Playing view is in the black style. The transition between them is animated with a crossfade. I want to do that.

My first attempt:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"whatever" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlack
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

No joy, it pops to black. Takers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated:YES];
```

Comment: Note that the above does not need to be nested in your animation block.